# Vue js how to hide the query strings from url throughout the project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

If my routes object is like this,

```js
const my_routes = [
  {
          path: "/dashboard",
          component: dashboard
        },
        {
          path: "/banners",
          component: banners
        },
        {
          path: "/paper-types",
          component: paper_types
        },
        {
          path: "/knowledge-areas",
          component: knowledge_areas
        },
]
```

It will always display in the browser url like this

```
www.someurl.com/dashboard
www.someurl.com/banners
www.someurl.com/paper-types
www.someurl.com/knowledge-areas
```

I want to display only the web url (www.someurl.com) throughout all the time.

Is this possible to achieve in vue js?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It would be awful for an end user.

Comment: @JamesCoyle i agree, but OP maybe builds a simple app that does not need that, which then you do not need router at all, just show/hide components based on actions.

Comment: @JamesCoyle Mostly I want to know how to do this. I am not going to apply it in production. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that, by simply configuring the [`mode` option of Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode):

```
new VueRouter({
  routes: my_routes,
  mode: 'abstract'
});
```

**Note:** However, you might want to consider the usability by activating abstract mode: when your user navigates throughout your web application, they will no longer be able to deeplink into the state they were last at, since the state is no longer reflected in the hash or URL path.

Comment: I did that then my app gets blank in the entry point (http://localhost:8081) nothing displayed only I can see a blank page now. I have a default route {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: welcome
    }, will this affect?

Comment: @PathumSamararathna, here is an answer from Evan You (creator of Vue) about vue-router abstract mode and `blank-page` trouble: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/729#issuecomment-252397275

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions i.e. vue-router 4.0.4, you must use createMemoryHistory() as below while creating your router:

```html
const router = createRouter({    
    history: createMemoryHistory(),
    routes,    
});
```

You can find other options [here.](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/index.html#new-history-option-to-replace-mode)